# how to get id in 2012061000001 format

Tags: mysql

I have following table structure there is column vid in that i want entry todays date followed by 00001 like '2012061000001'and when next time table get updated vid should be '20120610000002'
when if tommorow table will get update then vid should be 2012061100003

```
+----+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | vid  | visitorname | company | contact    | whometomeet |
+----+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL | rakesh      | godrej  | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
|  2 | NULL | samir       | infosys | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
+----+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

how can we achieve this?

here is my table structure where i set id as auto_increment can we have two fields auto_increment

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vid         | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visitorname | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| company     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| whometomeet | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And firing folowing query i got result like below

insert into visitor(vid)values(concat(replace(left(current_timestamp,10),'-',''),lpad('1','5','0')));

```
+----+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | vid           | visitorname | company | contact    | whometomeet |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL          | rakesh      | godrej  | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
|  2 | NULL          | samir       | infosys | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
|  3 | 2012061000001 | NULL        | NULL    | NULL       | NULL        |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

but problem is each time i will get that 1 there in vid if tommorow also i run this query i willl get tommorow date but that would be followed by that 00001 i want it 00002.

Comment: Do you want this column to be created at record insertion time? By next time the table gets updated, do you mean the next time a record is inserted or something else?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem you want to be solving; what exactly are your needs? Why do you need to have a `vid` that changes every day?

Comment: I think this can be solved with 2 columns, one for the `dateUpdated` and one for the `revisionNumber`. But this can have other (better) approuchs, depending on your business problem, including a trigger.

Comment: Try to explain why do you need the data in this format on your database, so we can give you a more reasonable way to store it.

Comment: @rcdmk:actually i want that id to print on pass for visitor

Comment: Can you change the table structure? If so, see amaidment's answer. If not, I can give you an idea with a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Comment: @ rcdmk: if I change table structure then again while getting id on pass for visitor I have to concat two columns in that i won't get id 2012061100001 format which will be like 201206111....how can we do this with trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you don't want to combine columns like that - it makes running queries relating to those fields a real pain (i.e. inefficient...)

Instead, have a `date` column and an `vid` column. e.g.

```
+----+----------+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | date     | vid  | visitorname | company | contact    | whometomeet |
+----+----------+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 20120610 |    1 | rakesh      | godrej  | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
|  2 | 20120610 |    2 | samir       | infosys | 9987654123 | abcdef      |
+----+----------+------+-------------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Then you can select on events on a given date.

Depending upon what your use case is, you could even make `vid` an `AUTO_INCREMENT`. (Although at that point, it's hard to tell the difference between `id` and `vid`.)

Comment: Exactly what I have said. This can be even indexed to bust performance on reports or lists of this data on your app.

Comment: @ amaidment: I accepted your answer but stil not satisfied with that way.please suggest another way

Comment: @ybc126 - why do you want another way? i.e. how does this approach fail to answer your question?

Comment: @amaidment: it's not fail but using trigger could help in better way I feel

Comment: @ybc126 - I disagree. A database should be designed with how you want to get the data out in mind - as such splitting into different columns is better. If you want an example using trigger, ask rcdmk.

Comment: @rcdmk:please help me on above question using trigger?